# Freeze first row of all worksheets in workbook (Python)

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Quick question.

I am using xlsxwriter to edit my worksheets.
I have 7 worksheets in my workbook and I'd like to freeze the first row of these 7 worksheet.
For this purpose:

```
worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0)
```

worked out for me. However, I wrote this line for each worksheet.

Then, I tried to iterate over a list of worksheet names as follows:

```
sheets = ['worksheet', 'worksheet2', 'worksheet3', 'worksheet4', 'worksheet5', 'worksheet6', 'worksheet7', 'worksheet8']
        
        for i in range(len(sheets)):
            sheets[i].freeze_panes(1, 0)
```

I got the error message:
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'freeze_panes'**

Is there a way to do this? Not calling sheet by sheet?

Thank you in advance!

** UPDATE **

```
for i in range(len(sheets)):
   workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(sheets[i]).freeze_panes(1, 0)
```

or

```
for sheet in sheets: 
   workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(sheets[sheet]).freeze_panes(1, 0)
```

Not working either.

Comment: `sheets` is a list of strings.  Strings don't have that method.  Perhaps you wanted something like `workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(sheets[i]).freeze_panes(1, 0)`

Comment: Quick note: `for i in range(len(sheets))::` is better written as `for sheetname in sheets:`.

Comment: Right, but still not working for me. See the traceback:     workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(sheets[i]).freeze_panes(1, 0) # Freeze the first row.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'freeze_panes'

Comment: From the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html): "The `get_worksheet_by_name()` method returns the worksheet or chartsheet object with the the given name or `None` if it isn’t found." At least one of your sheet names doesn't exist and therefore `get_worksheet_by_name()` is returning `None`.

Comment: I'm sorry, Steven, but I printed out worksheet names and they're correct, they exist. Unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure? Check by doing `for worksheet in workbook.worksheets():print(worksheet.get_name())`  Or just dispose of names altogether: `for worksheet in workbook.worksheets():worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to freeze panes on every worksheet just do

```
worksheet in workbook.worksheets():
    worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0)
```